# How to work with the C++ class members individually and at the same time as a whole?

Tags: c++, loops, collections, iteration

I have following C++ code

Rectangle.h

```
class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle(int _id);
    void draw();
    int getId();
private:
    int id;
};
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

Rectangle::Rectangle(int _id) {
    id = _id;
}
void Rectangle::draw() {
    std::cout << "Drawing rectangle with id: " << id << std::endl;
}

int Rectangle::getId() {
    return id;
}
```

RectangleCollection.h

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

class RectanglesCollection {
public:
    Rectangle rectangle_00;
    Rectangle rectangle_01;
    Rectangle rectangle_02;
    Rectangle rectangle_03;
        
    RectanglesCollection();
        
    void update();
};
```

RectangleCollection.cpp

```
#include "RectanglesCollection.h"

RectanglesCollection::RectanglesCollection() : 
rectangle_00(10),
rectangle_01(20),
rectangle_02(30),
rectangle_03(40)
{}
    
void RectanglesCollection::update() 
{
    rectangle_00.draw();
    rectangle_01.draw();
    rectangle_02.draw();
    rectangle_03.draw();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "RectanglesCollection.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    RectanglesCollection rectangles;
    rectangles.update();
    
    std::cout << "Id of the first rectangle in collection of rectangles: " << rectangles.rectangle_00.getId() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

My question is whether there is a possibility how I can avoid repeating the code inside the `RectanglesCollection::update` method and instead of that to use some loop iterating directly above the individual `Rectangle` members? It would be ideal if the user of the collection need not do anything else than define the instances of the `Rectangle` class. At the same time I would like to preserve the possibility to work with the Rectangle members individualy like `rectangles.rectangle_00.getId()`.

Comment: Use vectors (if the number of elements could change at run-time) or arrays?

Comment: You generally loop over arrays or other containers. Just put your rectangles in some sort of container and loop over it.

Comment: You are looking for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you represent your Rectangle member variables instead as a `std::array<Rectangle, 4>` in your RectanglesCollection, you can then easily access them by index and an `operator[](size_t)` accessor member function.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::array;
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::out_of_range;
using std::size_t;

// NAME_OF for String-ify.
#define NAME_OF(x) #x

class Rectangle {
    int _id;
public:
    Rectangle(int id);
    void draw(ostream&) const;
    auto id() const -> int;
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(int id_) : _id{id_} { }

void Rectangle::draw(ostream& out) const {
    out << "Drawing rectangle with id: " << id() << "\n";
}

auto Rectangle::id() const -> int {
    return _id;
}

class RectanglesCollection {
    array<Rectangle, 4> rectangles = {10, 20, 30, 40};
public:
    auto operator[](size_t i) const -> Rectangle;
    void display() const;
};

auto RectanglesCollection::operator[](size_t i) const -> Rectangle {
    if (i >= rectangles.size())
        throw out_of_range(NAME_OF(i));

    return rectangles[i];
}

void RectanglesCollection::display() const {
    for (auto&& r : rectangles) {
        r.draw(cout);
    }
}

int main() {
    auto rectangles = RectanglesCollection();
    rectangles.display();
    cout << "Id of the first rectangle in collection of rectangles: " << rectangles[0].id() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The solution you are suggesting also popped up in my head. But there are some drawbacks which I would like to avoid. At first I need to work with the rectangles like `rectangles[0]` instead of `rectangle_xyz` i.e. I need to remember at which index the specific rectangle is placed. The second problem is that I need to specify the number of rectangles to be able to allocate the array. As I have mentioned in my question I would like to somehow automate that task. Maybe somehow via the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @ProfessorJimatura • You could make an `auto rectangle_xyz() const -> Rectangle { return rectangles[0]; }` accessor member function to name the indexes, and use those instead of having to keep in mind specific index positions with some meta-semantic.  If the number of rectangles is variable, a `std::vector` would be more better suited, but that would be difficult to reconcile with specifically named member function accessors.  Automating the task is probably better suited using `template` parameterization.